# How can i solve the yield and the * for Redux/Saga

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga, yield

how can i solve this situation below?

```
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects'

import cart from './cart/sagas'

export default function* rootSaga() {
return yield all([
cart,
])
}
```

This error keeps occurring:
'yield' expression implicitly results in an 'any' type because its containing generator lacks a return-type annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I just descovered

```
export default function* rootSaga(): Generator {
  return (
     yield all([cart])
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you export all your sagas in the root saga file, you can use **fork**

From the docs: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RootSaga/

> Using unique yield fork will give back a task descriptor as many times as you have items in your saga array times.
> The resulting behavior in your app is that all of your sub-sagas are
> started and executed in the same order. Since fork is non-blocking,
> the rootSaga can finish while the child sagas continue to run and be
> blocked by their internal effects.

So, as you build out your app, it will look like

```
import { fork, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';

    export default function* rootSaga() {
      yield all(
        [
          cart,
          newThingHere,
          newThingHere,
          ...
        ].map(fork)
      );
    }
```